# Как сравнить класс и список

Tags: c#, linq

Есть класс **DB**

```
 class DB
 {
   private List<string> newList;
   public string Naimenovanie { get; set; }
   public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

В дальнейшем я использую `List<DB> listDB = new List<DB>();` чтобы в цикле вставлять экземпляры класса `DB`.

Есть также отдельно список `List<string> urls = new List<string>();`

Как сравнить элементы класса `listDB.Url` и `urls` и удалить из `listDB` те элементы url которых равен url списка `urls`

Я вижу это как создание двойного цикла и сравнение элементов. Думаю есть простое решение через `linq`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы избежать двойного цикла, я бы сложил `url`, которые надо удалить, в `HashSet`:

```
var urlSet = new HashSet<string>(urls);
```

После этого вам достаточно просто

```
listDB.RemoveAll(db => urlSet.Contains(db.Url));
```

Это не совсем LINQ, но, думаю, самый быстрый способ, если у вас достаточно большие списки.

Если оба списка маленькие, наверное, скорее будет обойтись без вспомогательного множества:

```
listDB.RemoveAll(db => urls.Contains(db.Url));
```

При этом `urls.Contains` пробегает цикл по списку `urls` (а вот `urlSet.Contains` даёт ответ за O(1)).

Answer (score 3):

```
List<DB> listDB = new List<DB>()
{
    new DB { Url = "test1" },
    new DB { Url = "test2" },
    new DB { Url = "test3" },
    new DB { Url = "test4" },
};

List<string> urls = new List<string>()
{
    "test2",
    "test5"
};

listDB.RemoveAll(x => urls.Exists(y => y == x.Url));
```

из listDB удалится 2ой елемент